# Profiler in CLion 2022.2.4 over WSL 2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, clion, wsl-2, perf

I am wanting to run a CPU profiler on my C++ code via CLion. The profiler in CLion only used to be available for Linux (using perf) and macOS (using DTrace), but as of [CLion 2021.2](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2021/07/clion-2021-2-eap-profiling-wsl-cmake-presets-lldb-12/), the profiler is supposed to be available for WSL (also using perf) and I am using CLion 2022.2.4. [CLion's docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/cpu-profiler.html) have also been updated to reflect this change, listing WSL under the supported OSs, but there is no additional information for it, so I would assume the steps would be identical to those of Linux.

perf is only available for WSL on WSL 2, but I *am* using WSL 2 and have successfully installed perf. I have configured a CLion toolchain for this same WSL instance, and have successfully managed to use another WSL-only feature (Valgrind MemCheck) through it.

However, with Valgrind, all Valgrind-related IDE features (settings, run configurations, notifications...) were available to me before I even installed WSL, whereas the equivelant features for profiling don't seem to be available even after completely configuring WSL 2. How can I access the profiler for WSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, CLion has a plugin called Copyright enabled, but it appears I must have disabled it. There is [a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-29340) which causes profiler-related features to only show with this plugin enabled, and enabling it fixed the issue.